# How to show a large data set with animated filtering?

Tags: performance, animation, react-virtualized

I was wondering if that would be doable to combine virtualization with animated filtering such as for instance what mixtitup provides: https://www.kunkalabs.com/mixitup/

The idea would be to present a lot of items (let say 30K images to represent), virtualize them and have the nice and smooth filtering animations of such library as mixitup.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This type of animation (rearranging/reordering) isn't really supported by react-virtualized. I know people who do animated scroll-tos or animated reveals for new rows, and there are libs like [clauderic/react-sortable-hoc](https://github.com/clauderic/react-sortable-hoc) that do animated drag-and-drop but the type of animation you linked to is a lot more involved.

You *might* be able to implement this by [providing your own (stateful) `cellRangeRenderer`](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/Grid.md#cellrangerenderer). `Grid` would manage windowing for you but you'd have to manage your own transitions. I've never tried it though.

If you *do* do something like that- I'd love to see it. Perhaps we could make a reusable component out of it.